# Как правильно подключить пользовательский модуль Node.js

Tags: node.js

Есть два файла: **server.js** и **module.j**s. В первом находится определение сервера, который запускает приложение на localhost. Во втором находится функция простого чтения из локального файла.

Как импортировать этот модуль в код сервера и выполнить функцию из него?

Пробовал сделать так, но ничего не получилось:

***server.js***

```
var connect = require('connect')
  , http = require('http')
  , reader = require('./module.js')
  , app
  ;

app = connect()
  .use(connect.static('dev'))
  .use('/js/lib/', connect.static('node_modules/requirejs/'))
  .use('/node_modules', connect.static('node_modules'))
  ;

http.createServer(app).listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Running on http://localhost:8080');
});

reader.readLines();
```

***module.js***

```
var fs = require('fs');

function readLines(file) {
    var raw = fs.readFileSync('file.txt').toString().split("\n");
    for(i in raw) {
        console.log(raw[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В модуле добавьте:

```
module.exports.readLines = readLines;
```